# Little-O notation on vector norm

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition

I was given the following definition of a total derivative (in multivariable calculus).

> Let there be $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{k}$, $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$, $x\in A^{\circ}$.
> We say $f$ is totally differentiable if there exists $T\in \text{Hom}\left(\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ such that $$\underset{v\to0}{\lim}\frac{f\left(x+v\right)-f\left(x\right)-T\left(v\right)}{\left\Vert v\right\Vert}=0$$ or equivalently$$f\left(x+v\right)=f\left(x\right)+T\left(v\right)+r\left(v\right)$$
> where $r$ is an error term that satisfies $$r\left(v\right)=o\left(\left\Vert v\right\Vert \right)$$

I don't understand the equivalent definition. Surely $r\left(v\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\left\Vert v\right\Vert \in \mathbb{R}$. What does "$r\left(v\right)=o\left(\left\Vert v\right\Vert \right)$" mean? Shouldn't it have been
"$\left\Vert r\left(v\right)\right\Vert=o\left(\left\Vert v\right\Vert \right)$"?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map) also makes use of a similar definition. What am I missing?

Comment: Either is okay and defined but they mean different things.  One is a statement about scalar valued functions and the other vector valued functions

Comment: What are the statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both statements $r(v)=o(\|v\|)$ and $\|r(v)\|=o(\|v\|)$ are valid.  Just go back to the definition for small-o.
$$(i)\qquad r(v)=o(\|v\|)\iff \lim_{\|v\|\to0}\frac{r(v)}{\|v\|}=0$$
and
$$(ii)\qquad \|r(v)\|=o(\|v\|)\iff \lim_{\|v\|\to0}\frac{\|r(v)\|}{\|v\|}=0$$
One limit (the first) involves a vector valued function $r(v)$ and the other a scalar valued function $\|r(v)\|$.  I think you can show that these two conditions are equivalent by writing out the $\varepsilon-\delta$ formulation.  Let's do that. Assume $r(v)=o(\|v\|)$ as $\|v\|\to0$ and let $\varepsilon>0$ then we know there is $\delta>0$ so that for any $v$ with $\|v\|<\delta$ we have
$$\Big \|\frac{r(v)}{\|v\|}\Big\|<\varepsilon$$
which is equivalent(using properties of norms)
$$\frac{\|r(v)\|}{\|v\|}<\varepsilon\implies \lim_{\|v\|\to0}\frac{\|r(v)\|}{\|v\|}=0 $$
and so $ \|r(v)\|=o(\|v\|)$ as $\|v\|\to0$.  The other direction can be seen by following the chain of implications in the reverse direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought that the purpose of asymptotic notation was for comparing 2 functions that act upon the same set and return values in the same set (namely share both the domain and codomain). I guess its usages are broader